# Реализация нескольких раскладов сочетаний клавиш в JavaScript-приложении

Tags: javascript

Рассматривается задача назначения горячих клавиш в JavaScript-приложении.

Есть JS-приложение, в котором определены некоторые сочения клавиш:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){

    if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // Alt+Shift+T
        e.preventDefault();
        // что-то произойдёт
    }
    else if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 89) { // Ctrl+Shift+T
        e.preventDefault();
        // ещё что-то произойдёт
    }

    //...
}
```

Потом мы вызвали всплывающее окно с элементами управления. Теперь нам надо, какие-то из определённых ранее комбинаций клавиш выполняли другие функции, а все остальные - и вовсе перестали реагировать, пока работа во всплывающем окне не будет завершена.

Я на данный момент думаю реализовать это так:

```
// При вызове окна
$(document).off('keydown'); // убираем старый обработчик 
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    executeCommandAccordingPopupLayout(e); // добавляем новый
    // Роберт Мартин заповедовал давать имена функций чётко отражающие их суть, даже если они длинные =)
}

// При закрытии окна
$(document).off('keydown'); // убираем новый обработчик
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    executeCommandAccordingDefaultLayout(e);
}

function executeCommandAccordingPopupLayout(event){
    // прописываем все поддерживаемые сочетания
}

function executeCommandAccordingDefaultLayout(event){
    // аналогично
}
```

Какие существуют альтернативные подходы решения данной задачи?

Comment: у вас две функции с одинаковым названием `executeCommandAccordingDefaultLayout`

Comment: @ThisMan, исправил. Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем отключать старый обработчик, введите некоторое состояние, например `layout` и простым `switch` вызывайте нужные обработчики

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    switch(layout) {
        case 'popup': {
            executeCommandAccordingPopupLayout(e)
            break;
        }
        default: executeCommandAccordingDefaultLayout(e);;
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Действительно, так лучше.